# how to get the template homepage back on storefront?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I installed storefront and at the end I untick the default homepage so it didn't create that page. So once the starter guide of storefront is over how can I get that default homepage back?
I tried deleting and installing the theme again but somehow that starter guide doesn't show up again. 
I really want the layout of the default template, is there anyway I can get it back?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the homepage template to a page.

1. Go to **Dashboard > Pages > All Pages**
2. Click on **Add New** to create a page
3. On the right you will find a box title **Page Attributes**
4. Select Homepage from Template
5. Click on **Publish**.

Now if you want to show this page as your homepage, go to Settings > Reading and make sure A static page (select below) is selected. Select the the page you've created earlier. Then click on Save Changes.